# Obtaining page maximum height in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if I am specific enough,

But I created a lightbox-style fadein background but it appears to me that the background won't reach the very bottom of the page. So when I scroll, the white background appears again.

Here is the demo:
http://jsbin.com/limiyisi/1/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="overlay"></div>   

<a  style="position:absolute;" href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="active">    
Button </a>
<div class="ex-height"></div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height : 100%;
background: #000;
top: 0;
left: 0;

opacity:0;
transition: opacity .3s;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
}


.backdrop {
opacity: 0.4 !important;
}

.ex-height {
height: 1204px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {

function toggle() {
   $('#overlay').toggleClass('backdrop');
   }

 $('[data-toggle="active"]').click(toggle);

 });
```

Thanks for any helpful advice!

Comment: to get the whole page's height you do: `pageHeight = $( document ).height();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of the overlay to the document's height:

```
$('#overlay').toggleClass('backdrop').height($(document).height());
```

Comment: Awesome!
Really simple but really difficult for beginners like myself to solve the problem with the correct code!

Answer (score 0):

Change the #overlay to

```
#overlay {
position:absolute;
background: #000;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;

opacity:0;
transition: opacity .3s;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

If that doesn't quite work - try changing the bottom and right values to 100%

Answer (score -1):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/limiyisi/3/edit)

```
$(function() {

  function toggle() {
    var pageHeight = $('html, body').innerHeight();
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('backdrop').height( pageHeight  ); 
  }

  $('[data-toggle="active"]').click(toggle);

});
```

Comment: 46k; you should know not to post code-only answers. Please add an explanation to your code.